# Equivalent circuit composed entirely in NAND gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, nand

**Summary / Instructions**

I was given this problem in a test paper:

Take this circuit
[image]

and make an equivalent one only with NAND gates.

---

**The problem**

I've tried, with multiple combinations but almost always the result is in this form:

`X+X+X`

Where it's supposed to be in this form X*X+X, the function of the above circuit.

NOT A AND NOT B AND C , ~A*~B + C (~ = NOT, * = AND, + = OR)

**Statement**

I know I'm not supposed to just throw the problem ( like asking others to get it solve ) but I'm feeling frustrated and I have a final exam soon and I know this kind of question will be in, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: De Morgan's laws might be useful.

Comment: The logic function is `~(A*B)+C`, or `~A+~B+C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OR gate can be made with only NAND gate (the most common gate btw) thanks to DeMorgan's theorem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo7mlD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can find on [this website](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-7/demorgans-theorems/) some more simplification in the world of boolean algebra.

Comment: Normally I'd criticise an answer that just handed over an homework/exam answer rather than gave guidance. But I can't see any way of answering it in smaller steps, it's a DeMorgan's question, so good answer.